# How to get HResult codes from IIS

Tags: iis, http, 500-error

I'm facing an 500 HTTP error from IIS (both on Chrome Client and from IIS logs) but I wonder If I can have more details about 500 HTTP error in order to narrow down my issue.
I found this article : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942031

> My question is : How I can have access to HResult code from IIS?

Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the IIS service server. You can review the 50X errors in the Application log in the event viewer. Depending on the error, you might find some hints in the IIS log, but 500's are generally more details in the application log.

500 means something bad happened and the application had to stop.